# Structure and style of Enigma Machine

Tags: performance, c, cryptography, enigma-machine

I took a little time and wrote the following code to produce enigma encryption.  I don't normally write code in C so  I would like to get feedback on the way it has been structured and any issues a more experienced C programmer might spot in the way I used structs, command line parsing, and the indexing around the strings to replicate the turning of rotors.

I did not create a separate header file since the code is so short I thought it would be best to just have a single file.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROTATE 26

const char *alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const char *rotor_ciphers[] = {
    "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ",
    "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE",
    "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO",
    "ESOVPZJAYQUIRHXLNFTGKDCMWB",
    "VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK",
    "JPGVOUMFYQBENHZRDKASXLICTW",
    "NZJHGRCXMYSWBOUFAIVLPEKQDT",
    "FKQHTLXOCBJSPDZRAMEWNIUYGV"
};

const char *rotor_notches[] = {"Q", "E", "V", "J", "Z", "ZM", "ZM", "ZM"};

const char *rotor_turnovers[] = {"R", "F", "W", "K", "A", "AN", "AN", "AN"};

const char *reflectors[] = {
    "EJMZALYXVBWFCRQUONTSPIKHGD",
    "YRUHQSLDPXNGOKMIEBFZCWVJAT",
    "FVPJIAOYEDRZXWGCTKUQSBNMHL"
};

struct Rotor {
    int             offset;
    int             turnnext;
    const char*     cipher;
    const char*     turnover;
    const char*     notch;
};

struct Enigma {
    int             numrotors;
    const char*     reflector;
    struct Rotor    rotors[8];
};

/*
 * Produce a rotor object
 * Setup the correct offset, cipher set and turn overs.
 */
struct Rotor new_rotor(struct Enigma *machine, int rotornumber, int offset) {
    struct Rotor r;
    r.offset = offset;
    r.turnnext = 0;
    r.cipher = rotor_ciphers[rotornumber - 1];
    r.turnover = rotor_turnovers[rotornumber - 1];
    r.notch = rotor_notches[rotornumber - 1];
    machine->numrotors++;

    return r;
}

/*
 * Return the index position of a character inside a string
 * if not found then -1
 **/
int str_index(const char * str, int character) {
    char * pos;
    int index;
    pos = strchr(str, character);

    // pointer arithmetic
    if (pos){
        index = (int) (pos - str);
    } else {
        index = -1;
    }

    return index;
}

/*
 * Cycle a rotor's offset but keep it in the array.
 */
void rotor_cycle(struct Rotor *rotor) {
    rotor->offset++;
    rotor->offset = rotor->offset % ROTATE;

    // Check if the notch is active, if so trigger the turnnext
    if(str_index(rotor->turnover, alpha[rotor->offset]) >= 0) {
        rotor->turnnext = 1;
    }
}

/*
 * Pass through a rotor, right to left, cipher to alpha.
 * returns the exit index location.
 */
int rotor_forward(struct Rotor *rotor, int index) {

    // In the cipher side, out the alpha side
    index = (index + rotor->offset) % ROTATE;
    index = str_index(alpha, rotor->cipher[index]);
    index = (ROTATE + index - rotor->offset) % ROTATE;

    return index;
}

/*
 * Pass through a rotor, left to right, alpha to cipher.
 * returns the exit index location.
 */
int rotor_reverse(struct Rotor *rotor, int index) {

    // In the cipher side, out the alpha side
    index = (index + rotor->offset) % ROTATE;
    index = str_index(rotor->cipher, alpha[index]);
    index = (ROTATE + index - rotor->offset) % ROTATE;

    return index;

}

/*
 * Run the enigma machine
 **/
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct Enigma machine = {}; // initialized to defaults
    int i, character, index;

    // Command line options
    int opt_debug = 0;
    int opt_r1 = 3;
    int opt_r2 = 2;
    int opt_r3 = 1;
    int opt_o1 = 0;
    int opt_o2 = 0;
    int opt_o3 = 0;

    // Command Parsing
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0) opt_debug = 1;
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-r") == 0) {
            opt_r1 = atoi(&argv[i+1][0])/100;
            opt_r2 = atoi(&argv[i+1][1])/10;
            opt_r3 = atoi(&argv[i+1][2]);
            i++;
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-o") == 0) {
            opt_o1 = atoi(&argv[i+1][0])/100;
            opt_o2 = atoi(&argv[i+1][1])/10;
            opt_o3 = atoi(&argv[i+1][2]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    if(opt_debug) {
        printf("Rotors set to : %d %d %d \n", opt_r3, opt_r2, opt_r1);
        printf("Offsets set to: %d %d %d \n", opt_o3, opt_o2, opt_o1);
    }

    // Configure an enigma machine
    machine.reflector = reflectors[1];
    machine.rotors[0] = new_rotor(&machine, opt_r1, opt_o1);
    machine.rotors[1] = new_rotor(&machine, opt_r2, opt_o2);
    machine.rotors[2] = new_rotor(&machine, opt_r3, opt_o3);

    while((character = getchar())!=EOF) {

        if (!isalpha(character)) {
            printf("%c", character);
            continue;
        }

        character = toupper(character);

        // Plugboard
        index = str_index(alpha, character);
        if(opt_debug) {
            printf("Input character ******** %c \n", character);
        }

        // Cycle first rotor before pushing through,
        rotor_cycle(&machine.rotors[0]);

        // Double step the rotor
        if(str_index(machine.rotors[1].notch,
                    alpha[machine.rotors[1].offset]) >= 0 ) {
            rotor_cycle(&machine.rotors[1]);
        }

        // Stepping the rotors
        for(i=0; i < machine.numrotors - 1; i++) {
            character = alpha[machine.rotors[i].offset];

            if(machine.rotors[i].turnnext) {
                machine.rotors[i].turnnext = 0;
                rotor_cycle(&machine.rotors[i+1]);
                if(opt_debug) {
                    printf("Cycling  rotor :%d \n", i+1);
                    printf("Turnover rotor :%d \n", i);
                    printf("Character  is  :%c \n", character);
                }
            }
         }

        // Pass through all the rotors forward
        for(i=0; i < machine.numrotors; i++) {
            index = rotor_forward(&machine.rotors[i], index);
        }

        // Pass through the reflector
        if(opt_debug) {
            printf("Into reflector %c\n", alpha[index]);
            printf("Out of reflector %c\n", machine.reflector[index]);
        }

        // Inbound
        character = machine.reflector[index];
        // Outbound
        index = str_index(alpha, character);

        if(opt_debug) {
            printf("Index out of reflector %i\n", index);
            printf("->Reflected character %c \n", character);
        }

        // Pass back through the rotors in reverse
        for(i = machine.numrotors - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            index = rotor_reverse(&machine.rotors[i], index);
        }

        // Pass through Plugboard
        character = alpha[index];

        if(opt_debug) {
           printf("Plugboard index %d \n", index);
           printf("Output character ******** ");
        }
        putchar(character);

        if(opt_debug) printf("\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

During the command line parsing I would suggest using `else`

This

```
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0) opt_debug = 1;
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-r") == 0) {
```

Would be better written as

```
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0) opt_debug = 1;
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-r") == 0) {
           ....
```

To avoid unnecessary checks. (If it is -d then it cannot also be -r so why check?).

I would suggest you remove the `i++` in the middle of the loop. This is a problem because if someone only enters -r as a single command line argument then this line will access invalid memory. `if (strcmp(argv[i], "-o")...`

```
/* argc = 2, argv[1] = "-r" */
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0) opt_debug = 1;
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-r") == 0) {
        opt_r1 = atoi(&argv[i+1][0])/100;
        opt_r2 = atoi(&argv[i+1][1])/10;
        opt_r3 = atoi(&argv[i+1][2]);
        i++; /* i = 2 */
    }
    /* There is no argv[2]! */
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-o") == 0) {
```

It makes your code simpler if you leave the loop mechanics to the loop declaration `for (...)` and not mess around with the loop counter inside the loop.

If you're expecting an argument after -r you should explicitly check that it exists.

```
        /* Is i+1 < argc at this point? */
        opt_r1 = atoi(&argv[i+1][0])/100;
        opt_r2 = atoi(&argv[i+1][1])/10;
        opt_r3 = atoi(&argv[i+1][2]);
```

And the same goes for the length of these arguments. If argv[i+1] exists but is only 1 character long then you will be accessing invalid memory on the third atoi line. Use strlen to make sure the argument is as long as you expect it or check for the end of string '\0' character before each atoi.

On a style note, as someone reading your code I would ask that you not alternate between `char* c`, `char * c` and `char *c`. Like everything related to code style there is no "right" way or "wrong" way but it will help your readers if you pick a style and stick to it.

Comment: If argv[i] is "-d" then why should we check if it is also "-r"? I feel like I've explained my logic quite extensively. Could you please expand on "it's wrong"?

Comment: Adjusting the loop counter is so that I can get the number following the flag and then go past it.. the command would look like this `enigma -r123 -o123` where r is the rotor and o is the offset to start with.  I will look into it more.